# Почему в названиях классов люди часто используют два нижних подчёркивания/пробела?

Tags: html, css

Только недавно начал изучать языки CSS и HTML и при просмотре различных кодов страниц вижу, что люди крайне часто в названиях классов ставят в определённых случаях одно нижнее подчёркивание/пробел, а в других случаях два. К примеру block__text. Стало интересно, имеет ли это какое-то логическое или же техническое значение. Хотелось бы узнать у знающих людей :).

Answer (score 2):

Это методология [BEM](https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/), два нижних `_` обозначают либо блок, либо элемент (по разному пишут).